# How to match a JSON response value to Postman environment variable?

Tags: json, testing, integer, postman

If an environment variable is set in Postman, for example year, then I'd like to check if the JSON response for the field birthYear matches the value of the variable.

I am trying with the following test:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests['Contents'] = environment.year === jsonData.birthYear;
```

This test always fails. birthYear is 1910 and year is also 1910.

If I try the same test but for a field that has a string value then it works correctly - pass when the values match and fail when they don't.

How should I proceed in order to test the integer values as well as the string ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Strict Equality Comparison (`===`). Environments and globals in postman are all strings. So strict comparison with a number will fail. Instead use `==`

```
tests['Contents'] = environment.year == jsonData.birthYear;
```